# Pricing a European Option using Simulaitons

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, userform, finance

I have created a user form that allows the user to change the various variables involved in pricing an option (Exercise Price, volatility..etc) along with allowing the user to change the simulations needed to arrive at the Price (or mean price in this case). However, I am unable to call the public subs within my code once I click the **OK** Button. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. [I have also included a picture of my user form below]

[image: User Form]

```
   Option Explicit
      Private cancel As Boolean

        Public Function ShowInputsDialog(currentPrice As Single, _
        exercisePrice As Single, riskfreeRate As Double, _
        volatility As Single, duration As Single, simulation As Double) As Boolean

    Call Initialize
    Me.Show
    If Not cancel Then

     'Capture the other inputs.
        currentPrice = txtCurrentPrice.Text
        exercisePrice = txtExercisePrice.Text
        riskfreeRate = txtRiskfreeRate.Text
        volatility = txtVolatility.Text
        duaration = txtDuration.Text
        simulation = txtSimulation.Text

     ShowInputsDialog = Not cancel
    Unload Me
    End Function

     Public Sub ErrorCheck()
    ' Perform error checking for user inputs.

    If IsNumeric(currentPrice) = False Or currentPrice < 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a numeric value for the Current Price")
    End If
    If IsNumeric(exercisePrice) = False Or exercusePrice < 0 Then
         MsgBox ("Please enter a positive numeric value for the exercise price")
    End If
    If IsNumeric(riskfreeRate) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a numerical value for the risk-free rate")
    End If
    If IsNumeric(volatility) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a numerical value for the Standard deviation")
    End If
    If IsNumeric(duration) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a numerical valye for duration")
    End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Call_Eur(currentPrice As Single, _
        exercisePrice As Single, riskfreeRate As Double, _
        volatility As Single, duration As Single, simulation As Double)
        Dim stockPrice As Single
        Dim CallcashflowTermination As Single
        Dim PutcashflowTermination As Single
        Dim CalldiscountedValue As Double
        Dim PutdiscountedValue As Double
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim CallMean As Double
        Dim PutMean As Double
        Dim arrayCallPrice() As Integer
        Dim arrayPutPrice() As Integer
    For i = 1 To simulation
    ' stock price
    stockPrice = currentPrice * Exp((riskfreeRate - 0.5 * volatility ^ 2) * duration + volatility * Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 0, 1) * Sqr(duration))

    ' option cash flow at termination
    CallcashflowTermination = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, stockPrice - exercisePrice)
    PutcashflowTerminatio = Application.WorksheetFunction.Funciton.Max(0, exercisePrice - stockPrice)

    ' discounted value of the option
    CalldiscountedValue = CallcashflowTermination * Exp(-duration * riskfreeRate)
    PutdiscountedValue = PutcashflowTermination * Exp(-duration * riskfreeRate)

    arrayCallPrice(i) = CalldiscountedValue
    arrayPutPrice(i) = PutdiscountedValue

    CallMean = Application.WorsheetFunction.Average(arrayCallPrice)
    PutMean = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrayPutPrice)

    Next i

    MsgBox "The Call option price is " & CallMean & " the Put option price is " & PutMean

End Sub
 Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
    cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub CmdOK_Click() '<--- ERROR!!!
Call Call_Eur(currentPrice As Single, _
        exercisePrice As Single, riskfreeRate As Double, _
        volatility As Single, duration As Single, simulation As Double)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: the way you call Call_Eur is wrong syntax. You dont have to define the types of parameters when calling a sub.

Comment: @A.S.H When I don't define the parameters it still gives me a syntax error.  What other way could I call it?

Comment: I think you need to define (`Dim`) the variables (`exercisePrice`, `riskfreeRate ` etc) in a different way, i.e. as global scope.

Answer (score 0):

BIG RED FLAG!!!!

[image]

When calling a subroutine. you need to pass values into it.  Not redefine it's parameters.

```
Private Sub CmdOK_Click() '<--- ERROR!!!
    Call Call_Eur(12.50, 13.43, 14, 33.56, 100, 13.67)
End Sub
```

I prefer removing the parenthesis and not using Call at all.

```
Private Sub CmdOK_Click() '<--- ERROR!!!
    Call_Eur 12.50, 13.43, 14, 33.56, 100, 13.67
End Sub
```